# Select map section in Tableau

Tags: dictionary, latitude-longitude, tableau-api

I have two geo-maps in Tableau, in different sheets. Both are created from different data and therefore don't show the exact same geo section of the maps. E.g. the displayed section of the first map is a bit larger than the section of the second map because the coordinates extend over a larger geographical area.

Is there a way in Tableau to manually synchronize both maps in the different sheets? I search for a way to tell Tableau to display a map section from coordinates X1/Y1 (left top corner) to X2/Y2 (right bottom corner) however i failed to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a static background image instead of a dynamically generated map background. This allows you exact control of the map, corner coordinates, and where to clip the axis boundaries. It can also be faster and more robust if your connection to your map server is slow or unreliable.

The main downsides are that zooming won't automatically switch to more detailed maps just scale the image and that you don't get the background layer choices under map options.

To give it a try, use the Background Images panel from the Map menu